# Get the index of clicked items from name on the input field inside jquer repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery repeater and the input field looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.repeater').repeater({});
});
function getIndex(item){
    let index = $(item).index();
    console.log("index >>", index);
}
```

```html
<!-- outer repeater -->
<form class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="outer-list">
      <div data-repeater-item>
        <input onchange="getIndex(this)" type="text" name="text-input" value="A"/>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>

      </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
```

Here, the name field looks like: `name="outer-list[0][text-input]"`. Now, I want to retrieve this first index `[0]`. If the name field was `outer-list[1][text-input]` then this index should be returned as `1`. Here, is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k768y93L/)

Comment: can you show more codes ?

Comment: @Swati Could you be a little bit more precise on which part you want to see

Comment: If you explain what your ultimate goal is to be able to do, we may be able to give you a better approach than what you think the right approach is.

Comment: How these inputs are generated that part or proper html code .

Comment: I have updated the code, please take a look.

Comment: Use : `$(item).closest("[data-repeater-item]").index()` or `$(item).parent().index()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.repeater').repeater({
  show: function () {
       
        $(this).slideDown();
        
        var index = $(this).closest('[data-repeater-item]').index();
        //$(this).find('.index-span').text(index);
 
    },
 });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.